# Como fazer upload de maneira segura?

Tags: c#, segurança, criptografia, ftp

Como fazer *upload*/*download* de um arquivo em um servidor FTP sem que as informações de login deste servidor esteja visíveis no código? Por exemplo, eu **não** quero fazer o seguinte:

```
string FTPhost = "ftp://192.168.1.1/";
string FTPpass = "SenhaDoAcessoFTP";
string FTPuser = "Usuário";

FTPclient.Connect(FTPhost, FTPpass, FTPuser);
```

E essas informações podem ser facilmente vistas com um decompilador. Como eu oculto isso, e faço com que o usuário que está usando o aplicativo não tenha acesso à estas senhas **de maneira nenhuma**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De maneira alguma, não tem como. Pode criar alguns artifícios de criptografar a senha, mas como ela está na aplicação que o usuário tem controle, tem como decifrar, mesmo que demore. Na verdade nem precisa porque para enviar a aplicação tem que descriptografar e nesse momento é possível pegar a senha.

Se não quer que alguém pegue uma senha só tem um caminho: não entregue ela para ninguém, não importa a forma.

Senha é usada para dar segurança para uma pessoa, não para aplicações. Se pode fazer isso, ótimo, se não pode e precisa entregar, aceite a insegurança.

Certamente tem outros caminhos para obter segurança nesse nível, mas não usando senha e talvez não usando FTP. Mas nem sabemos o objetivo, as restrições, etc. Uma dica em [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/108402/101) ([outra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/141991/101)).

Veja [um tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14150/Encrypt-and-Decrypt-Data-with-C).