# Autenticação HTTP básica

Tags: android

Estou com uma duvida sobre autenticação básica. O problema é que eu tenho um webservice com slim framework e gostaria que apenas meu aplicativo acessasse as rotas que criei sem usuario ou senha. Como posso fazer isso? Todas as minhas rotas estão disponíveis pelo navegador, como bloquear acesso pelo navegador.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a [mesma técnica disponível para chamadas cross-domain](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/135293/d%C3%BAvida-sobre-seguran%C3%A7a-de-aplica%C3%A7%C3%B5es-cross-domain/141991#141991), *fixação de certificado* ou *certificate pinning*. A [documentação para desenvolvedores Android](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html) explica como o conceito funciona.

Copiando da outra resposta,

> Você garantirá assim que clientes Android apenas se conectarão ao servidor que você especifiar, e que o seu servidor de aplicação aceitará apenas conexões oriundas de clientes autorizados pelo certificado.